# Asynctask wait for SMS

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sms

I'm developing an app to manage M2M communication via SMS between the mobile and a hardware device, for internal test procedures.

To run the test, the operator should just touch a button, and the app should send some configuration command messages to the hardware device, and listen for the confirmation response of each message.

I have implemented a BroadcastReceiver where I listen for the incoming messages. Then, I use a callback interface to send this data (sender_number, message, time) to the UI activity.

So my `MainActivity` implements this interface, and I use an Asynctask to execute the test procedure.

This is the method of the callback interface which I use to get the data from the receiver in the UI.

```
public void gotSms(String num, String msg, long time) {
        mNumber = num;
        mMessage = msg;
        mTime = time;
    }
}
```

And this is the Asynctask where the test procedure runs:

```
class TestProcedure extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        /*First command*/
        String command1 = "DEV123"+"-"+"DEV-NUM1";
        /*Send SMS with command*/
        smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        try {
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(mNumber, null, command1, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("SMS_SENT", "Sending error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        //AFTER SMS IS SENT, I NEED TO WAIT TILL THE RECEVIER RECEIVES THE 
        //CONFIRMATION SMS TO GET THE OK
        /*Then the second command is sent*/
        String command2 = ...
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that for now I only get to send the command, I don't know how the Asynctask could *wait for the received SMS* and how the callback could *notify the Asynctask that the SMS has arrived*.

**Update -> Receiver definition**

I have the receiver declared in the manifest:

```
<receiver 
        android:name=".SmsReceiver" 
        android:exported="true" > 
        <intent-filter 
            android:priority="1000"> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Also, I have the callback interface declared in the SmsReceiver class:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public SmsReceiver(SmsUpdater updater) {
        smsUpdater = updater;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //...
    }

    public interface SmsUpdater {
        void gotSms(String num, String msg, long time, String imei);
    }
}
```

So in the MainActivity I implement `SmsUpdater` and I instantiate the receiver in OnCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    smsReceiver = new SmsReceiver(this);
    //...
}
```

**Update -> Code modification**

With the help of Mike M. I've changed some things in my code. The first is that I no longer use Asynctask. My current code looks like this:

I first obtain some values from the fragment in my main activity with this method. Also this method is the one launched when the user click on the start test button. This test is porformed sending 3 commands automatically and waiting for each one's response SMS before sending the next.

```
public void manageConfiguration(String pin, String number, String operator) {
    /*Saves values*/
    mPin = pin;
    mNumber = number;
    mOperator = operator;
    /*Sends first command*/
    configTnum1(pin, number);
}
```

This is how the sending command method looks like for this case:

```
public void configTnum1(String pin, String number) {
    /*Command generate*/
    String command = constructCommand(pin, "DEV+TNUM1", getPhoneNumber());
    //The command would look like: DEV1234,DEV+TNUM1,394876354;
    /*Sends SMS*/
    sendSMS(number, command);
}
```

When this command is sent, I should wait for the incoming message, that aside from giving me the confirmation (message OK or ERROR) it also gives me other info about the hardware device as it's GPS position, identification code, etc.. that I could need to use in any moment.

So, now I get in the critical point. Even if I do in Mike M.'s way implementing the receiver in the activity, or in my way using a callback to pass the data from the receiver to the activity... I get into the situation where I need to manage how I continue with the automatical test and send the command2.

Mike M. propose to manage this in the same receiver (or in the callback method in my code, it would be the same). And at first look seems a good option. But I have to explain that this test is not the only one I make. This test sends 3 commands automatically, but after doing this, I have other screen (activity) where the user must perfom another test where this time 5 commands are sent automatically. So, maybe I'm wrong but I think that if I manage all this on the receiver for the first test, it could make something wrong confusing booth tests.

Comment: You probably don't want to use an `AsyncTask` for this. You might consider initiating the command sequence in the Button's `onClick()` method, and implementing the Receiver so it then sends the next command upon confirmation in `onReceive()`, saving any necessary state information and disabling/enabling UI components as needed between sends/receipts.

Comment: @Mike M. I'll consider not to use Asynctask as you say, but could you provide an example to understand how the receiver could notify that the SMS has arrived? Also, how would the method wait since the SMS is sent till the confirmation is received?

Comment: I'm on my mobile at the moment, so it'll take a minute to put together an outline of what I mean. But think of it like this: you don't necessarily want to "wait" for the confirmation; you simply need the Receiver to fire the next command once it gets the confirmation. If you want to disallow user interaction in the interim, simply disable the relevant UI components. Make sense?

Comment: @Mike M. I think I understand now what do you mean. But data is managed in the Activity, not in the receiver, so the receiver doesn't know which command must launch. I mean that there are some diferent test procedures, for each one I create a diferent method, and having a first look at what I think you propose, I think it would be a bit messy to manage all that info in the receiver, but I wait for your explanation becasue I think maybe I'm not understanding well

Comment: How are you registering your BroadcastReceiver? If you've the class registered in the manifest, then yeah, it'll take some juggling to make it work. However, it sounds like you need only listen for incoming SMS while the app is active, in which case you should implement the Receiver as an instance of an inner class of the Activity. This would then have access to the Activity's state.

Comment: @Mike M. I have updated the post. In this test app, as you say I just need only listen for incoming SMS while it is running, but for the final commercial app It should be listening all the time for incoming SMS

Comment: @Mike M. Ok thanks, don't be hurry... I'll be checking this for a while and I'll come back with the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I do not know all of the details of your implementation, the following is, again, a sparse outline. I've run it myself, however, filling in incidental details as necessary, and I believe this should work as you need.

Since we've established that your app need only listen for incoming SMS while it's running, you don't need the `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the manifest. Again, I have it as an inner class of `MainActivity`, which will receive notification of the incoming message and then relay it to the appropriate `Fragment`. I took your last post update to mean that you're concerned that the separate tests would get "mixed up", and, as these tests won't run simultaneously, this shouldn't be a problem.

In `MainActivity`, we have the following (in addition to the boilerplate code):

```
private SmsTestListener listener = null;

private void sendSmsTest(String number, String command, SmsTestListener listener)
{
    this.listener = listener;
    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, command, null, null);
}   

private void notifyIncoming(String message)
{
    listener.onSmsTestResponse(message);
}

private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Standard decoding for SMS
        Object[] pdus = (Object[])intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        SmsMessage messageSegment;

        for (int i=0;i < pdus.length;i++)
        {
            messageSegment = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            message.append(messageSegment.getDisplayMessageBody());
        }

        if (isMessageValid(message.toString()))
        {
            notifyIncoming(message.toString());
        }
    }

    private boolean isMessageValid(String message)
    {
        // Check that the message is valid
        // Here, I've listed the message text for
        // the check, but you could also use the
        // originating number, etc.
        return true;
    }
};
```

We also need to define the following interface:

```
public interface SmsTestListener
{
    void onSmsTestResponse(String message); 
}
```

Then, the `Fragments`, which implement the above interface, would be structured as such:

```
class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements SmsTestListener
{
    private String number = "1234567890";
    private String[] commands;
    private int commandIndex;

    private Button startButton;

    private void startSmsTest()
    {
        // Initialize commands here
        // and fire the first one
        commands = new String[] { "command1", "command2" };
        commandIndex = 0;
        fireNextCommand();
    }

    private void fireNextCommand()
    {
        // Tell the Activity to send the next message,
        // and pass it a reference to the Fragment that
        // is running the test
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).sendSmsTest(number, commands[commandIndex], this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSmsTestResponse(String message)
    {
        // Increment our command counter and if
        // we're not finished, fire the next one
        commandIndex++;
        if (commandIndex < commands.length)
        {
            fireNextCommand();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test finished", 0).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // This is standard; I put it here to show our
        // start button initialization
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        startButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_execute);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    startSmsTest();
                }
            }
        );
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have update the post to provide a bit deeper explanation about what I need. Your aproach is a good idea, but my code is a bit more complicated than it appears at a first time, maybe with the new explanation you can get an idea. So I think that we should focus another way of trying to get this. I hope not to bother you, I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the new outline. I think I removed the code specific to my testing, but lemme know if things don't work. (I also deleted some of my comments down here just to clean up a little.)

Comment: Ok Mike, I think that this time I have all I need to continue with the app. Thanks for all your help